# Sequence limit sophisticated

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$\frac{3+(-1)^n+9\sqrt{n}-7n^5-2[\sqrt[3]{n}]n}{(3n-1)(n-2)(2n-3)(n-4)(4n-5)+2^{-n}}$$

What is the easiest method to calculate this sequences limit when $n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: I sure hope that it should be $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

We just need to consider the highest power of $n$ in the numerator and in the denominator. In the numerator the highest power of $n$ occurs in the $-7n^5$ term. All that those other terms in the numerator have a lower degree of $n$, or is just doing some silly thing like $(-1)^n$ which is not increasing at all. In the denomiator if we were to expand that product into a polynomial, the leading term would have the highest power of $n$ (the term will be $24n^5$). The limit is then the ratio of the coefficients of these two terms. Namely, the limit will be $-\frac{7}{24}$.